# Determining the largest non-whole number in C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that accepts 4 numbers, regardless if it is a whole or non-whole number. It will determine the largest non-whole number found in the inputs. If there are no non-whole numbers present, then it will print a message that there are none.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num1, num2, num3, num4;

    //Enter Numbers 
    printf("Enter 4 Numbers : ");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);

    //Numbers are Integer
    if ((num1 - (int) num1) == 0
        && (num2 - (int) num2) == 0
        && (num3 - (int) num3) == 0
        && (num4 - (int) num4) == 0) {
        printf("Output : No Non-Whole Numbers found\n");
    } else {
        //Numbers are Float
        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3 && num1 > num4) {
            printf("Output : %.1f\n", num1);
        } else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3 && num2 > num4) {
            printf("Output : %.1f\n", num2);
        } else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2 && num3 > num4) {
            printf("Output : %.1f\n", num3);
        } else {
            printf("Output : %.1f\n", num4);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have some problems with it, for example when a user inputs:

> Enter 4 Numbers : 12.5 15 2 1
> Output: 15
> Instead it should be 12.5

> Enter 4 Numbers : 10.5 10.5 7 8
> Output: 8.0
> Instead it should be 10.5

Comment: Your test consider that all your numbers are *not integers*, or that they are all integers. Also consider that the test `num1 - (int)num1) ==  0` could give false results. Better: compare the abs of the difference to a threshold.

Comment: How do I solve this problem? I have tried other ways but it still doesn't solve my issue. Can I have some tips or advice?

Comment: You're not accounting for `>=` (breaks the second text), and you not excluding whole numbers from your non-whole comparison list (breaks the first test). Fix both of those and it will work.

Comment: Your second case fails because you do not consider equality.  You have two numbers that are not greater than each other.  You probably need to use `>=`.  If you only want to look at whole numbers, you need to consider a dynamic list filtered to only whole numbers or adding in a bunch of additional booleans on which are whole numbers.

I suspect most programmers would not hardcode equality tests like you have but rather put the numbers (and in your case only the whole numbers) into an array and perform a search.

Comment: A text compare looking for a `.` might be more reliable in your use case. what if someone enters `1.1 2.00000000000000000000000000000001`?

Comment: Always (**yes, always**) prefer `double` for floating-point numbers. *Make rare exceptions (for `float` or `long double`) only after determining `double` does not match your requirements.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nils Martel pointed out this should be coded as a loop over an array.
The only difference from his implementation is that I think mine is easier to understand, because it's closer to the original code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE (0 != 0)
#define TRUE  (!FALSE)

#define ABS(x) ((x >= 0) ? (x) : (-x))

#define NUMS 4

int is_whole(float num)
{
    return (ABS(num) - (int)ABS(num)) == 0;
}

int main()
{
    float nums[NUMS];
    int contains_float = FALSE;
    int largest = 0; // Initialized with the first element

    //Enter Numbers 
    printf("Enter 4 Numbers : ");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", &nums[0], &nums[1], &nums[2], &nums[3]);

    //Numbers are Integer
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMS; ++i) {
        if (is_whole(nums[i]) == FALSE) {
            contains_float = TRUE;
            // The additional condition here accounts for the case when
            // nums[0] is the largest element in the array
            if (nums[i] > nums[largest] || is_whole(nums[largest]))
                largest = i;
        }
    }
    
    if (contains_float)
        printf("Output : %.1f\n", nums[largest]);
    else
        printf("Output : No Non-Whole Numbers found\n");
}
```

You can run it here https://onlinegdb.com/rkVwPZaZu

Comment: OH MY! I can understand your code and it's not that complicated, since I'm still a beginner :'> Thank yooou so much and I wish you a wonderful life!!!

Comment: You're welcome. However, I chose to be a software developer, I'm afraid it's too late to have a wonderful life :'D

Comment: How can it work with input `10 2.3 5 6`? I may miss something.

Comment: @damien Oh, you're right. I'm fixing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best check for determining, if a number is non while would be
`floor(n) != n`

Now, In your code you repeat yourself quite often and your logic gets quite complex and hard to understand by just looking at it.

You might find this exercise a great moment, to learn more about arrays and loops!

I've tried to rewrite your code using the `floor(n) != n` check, and by using arrays and loops. Mind, my C is a little rusty, but I hope you can reason with my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_largest_non_while(float *numbers, int length) {
  int is_set = 0;
  float greatest;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      float n = numbers[i];
      if (floor(n) != n) {
        // n is a non while number

          if (!is_set) {
            is_set = 1;
            greatest = n;
            continue;
          }

          if (greatest < n) greatest = n;
      }
  }

  if (is_set) printf("%f\n", greatest);
}

int main() {

  float num[4];

  // Enter Numbers
  printf("Enter 4 Numbers : ");
  scanf("%f %f %f %f", num, num + 1, num + 2, num + 3);

  print_largest_non_while(num, 4);
}
```

Comment: HUHUHU thank you! It worked. I will analyze and study your code. Thank you so much. :'>

Answer (score 0):

Your test consider that all your numbers are not integers, or that they are all integers. Also consider that the test `num1 - (int)num1) ==  0` could give false results. Better: compare the abs of the difference to a threshold.

```
#define N   4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float num[N];

    //Enter Numbers 
    printf("Enter %d Numbers : ", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int t = scanf ("%f", &num[i]);
        if (t != 1) return 1;
    }
    
    float eps = 1.0e-5;
    int found = 0;
    float vmax;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int check = fabs(num[i] - rint(num[i])) > eps;
        found += check;
        if (check) {
            if (found == 1) {
                vmax = num[i];
            } else {
                if (num[i] > vmax) {
                    vmax = num[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Numbers are all Integer if found == 0
    if(found == 0) {
        printf("Output : No Non-Whole Numbers found\n");
     } else {
         printf("Output : %.1f\n", vmax);
     }
    return 0;
}
```